# Spring Boot + Angular 4 : Automatically recompile frontend

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot

I'm developing an Angular4 + Spring Boot java web application with gradle. I've set up my gradle tasks as described in [this link](http://www.umeshmorsu.com/2017/04/28/spring-boot-and-angular-cli-example/). I am able to launch the entire web app by running `./gradlew bootRun` -- the java and typescript compile, and the website compiles.

When learning angular 4, I noted that when launching the server via nodejs, you can edit typescript files and others, and the frontend automatically recompiles and even the browser refreshes itself.

I am not sure how to get this same behavior in my spring boot / gradle setup. I believe that's the intent of the `buildClientWatch` and `buildClientDev` tasks. The setup is to have `buildClientDev` run as a dependency of bootRun, but I can't change frontend and provide new file. Perhaps it's becuase the files are being copied over and served from `src/main/resources/static`, which I'm honestly not sure why they're going there. Why not have them go to a `webapp` folder?

I also tried manually running `buildClientWatch` in a separate terminal, but that doesn't seem to actually do anything, although it does seem to print out and identify that files are changing.

Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/stealthrabbi/spring-boot-mvc-test/tree/dev/angular-4) (note the branch) that includes the build.

```
task buildClientDev(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall')
{
  group = 'build'
  description = 'Compile client side folder for development'
  args = ['run','buildDev']
}
task buildClient(type:NpmTask, dependsOn:'npmInstall')
{
  group = 'build'
  description = "Compile client side folder for production"
  args = ['run','build']
}
task buildClientWatch(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall')
{
  group = 'application'
  description = "Build and watches the client side assets for rebuilding"
  args = ['run','buildWatch']
}
bootRun.dependsOn(buildClientDev)
jar.dependsOn(buildClient)
```

Comment: The easiest way, IMO, is to start the backend with Spring Boot, start the frontend with ng serve, and configure the ng server to act as a proxy for the backend: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Please try with spring boot devtools library.
Use it with your client recompile tasks along with it.For more info please refer
https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3

Comment: why was your answer downvoted? Is this not a viable solution??

Comment: Don't know.It was the solution I suggested to my colleague.Anyway I will try it my self and inform you